# where to store apps for shiny-server on ubuntu server?

Tags: r, shiny-server

Sorry for this basic questions. I don't know where to put the folder (say folder called `"app1"` containing `"ui.R"` and `"server.R"` to serve on my shiny-server. I've confirmed my shiny-server is running, and I dropped my project folder into

```
/var/shiny-server/www
```

But when I then go to

```
my-ip-address:3838/app1
```

I get:

```
Page not found

Sorry, but the page you requested doesn't exist.
```

I figure I'm putting the files in the wrong place, but everything I read seems to suggest the `/www` folder of the `/shiny-server`. Where should these files go?

Answer (score 0):

Are you accepting connections on the configured port? What happens when you go your http://ip:3838 without the app directory? If shiny is running try copying the directory into /srv/shiny-server/ and then restarting shiny server.

Comment: then I see "Welcome to Shiny Server" along with the sample app on the side, everything working as it should be.

Comment: Try copying the directory into /srv/shiny-server/ and then restarting shiny server.

Comment: Yep yep, glad to help.